# Is there a way to send the tracking information to the phone number in the order?

Tags: shipment-tracking

I have a client who wants to send tracking information via SMS to the phone number in the order no matter is someone else calls in with the order information. Is that even possible

Comment: Not by default. You need to add some sms provider module and take services.

Comment: Yes, It is possible but you need to do your own customization or you can purchase some already built extensions for this. By default, this is not possible.